# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log_request_id.filters'

Tags: django, django-settings

While setting up the environment for project. I was using the command `python3 manage.py migrate_schemas` to migrate schemas and got this error.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log_request_id.filters'**

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "tenant_context": {"()": "tenant_schemas.log.TenantContextFilter"},
        "request_id": {"()": "**log_request_id.filters**.RequestIDFilter"},
    },
    ...
}
```

I have also used `source local.env` before using migrate_schemas command. I have tried installing, django_log_request_id and log_request_id, also tried to do some changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.